# How do I make 'Restore to ...' actually prompt me for a destination?

Tags: time-machine

Running 14.1.1 on a mac mini.

From the time machine 'starfield', I select a directory, click right, select 'Restore to ...'. But nothing prompts me for a destination, and then the attempt to restore to the old location fails for lack of disk space. Why does the menu item end with '...' if it's not going to ask me something?

Comment: 14.3.1 also ignores the ellipsis (my disk is not full). I suspect this is a bug. Workaround: Use Finder. I hate the starfield, and never use it except to test behaviour for questions like yours.